# what is syntax of conditional operator in Velocity script

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

I have a TaxItem object. if taxItem/rate of that object is null then need to show 0.0%. what is syntax of conditional operator in Velocity script.  Here I need to compare with null$!taxItem.rate

Tax Rate : $!taxItem.rate

**output:**

Tax Rate :

If I remove ! symbol

Tax Rate : $taxItem.rate

**output:**

Tax Rate : $taxItem.rate

But I want to print default value instead empty space.

Comment: For not null condition you could try !${taxItem.rate}.  #if (!${taxItem.rate}) ${taxItem.rate} #else 0.0% #end

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if your controller hands over a proper filled model to the view (e.g. with an allready filled in default value in such a situation)?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#if($taxItem.rate) 
        $taxItem.rate 
#else 
       0.0% 
#end
```